# could not find an overload for 'POST' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: swift, afnetworking-2

I'm quite new to swift and iOS thing. I ran to this error and I don't know how to fix it. My guess is that the constructingBodyWithBlock have an invalid argument but I don't know how to make it valid

Here are my code:

```
class func sendEmail(
    sendGridUrl: String,
    params: Dictionary<String, String>,
    fileData: NSData,
    name: String,
    fileName: String,
    mimeType: String,
    successCallback: (object: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> Void,
    errorCallback: (statusCode: Int) -> Void) {
        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
        let url = sendGridUrl
        manager.POST(url, parameters: params, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formdata: AFMultipartFormData) in
            formdata.appendPartWithFileData(fileData, name: name, fileName: fileName, mimeType: mimeType)
            }, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                successCallback(object: responseObject as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
            }, failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
                errorCallback(statusCode: error.code)
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`constructingBodyWithBlock` expects `((AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void)?`. You seem to have dropped the `!` in `(formdata: AFMultipartFormData)`